# Android : download content from URL which returns mp3 file

Tags: android

After 2 days of research, I didn't found any solution to my problem :/

I want to download an mp3 file, which is returned only after calling a URL in a browser.

I can't give you the actual url because I'm not allowed to due to rights restrictions, but it is of the form:

```
http://wscompany.name.com/downloadws/getDlFile/mdkHdKy97RppVWOsIOdDBuG/audio/1478
```

As you can see, this URL doesn't have the mp3 extension. So if I put this kind of URL in a browser on windows, it returns an MP3 to save onto the disk, which is fine. But if I want to call this URL in android in order to download the final file returned (the mp3), it doesn't work.

I tried with a url containing a mp3 file directly and it works very well (like http://www.mediacollege.com/downloads/sound-effects/urban/factory/Factory_External_01.mp3), but not with an url without the mp3 extension, even though it does returns an mp3, I hope you see what I mean.

Does anyone know how to do that in android ?

Here is my code, using an AsyncTask, called by

```
new Download(MyActivity.this, urlToCall).execute();
```

And the Download AsyncTask :

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    Context context;
    String urlDownload;

    public Download(Context context,String url) 
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.urlDownload=url;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Please wait, Download for " + urlDownload );
        Log.v("DOWNLOAD", "Wait for downloading url : " + urlDownload);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            //URL url = new URL("http://www.mediacollege.com/downloads/sound-effects/urban/factory/Factory_External_01.mp3");
            URL url = new URL(urlDownload);

            Log.w( "DOWNLOAD" , "URL TO CALL : " + url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //set up some things on the connection
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/MyDownloaded/") ;

            boolean success = true;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdir();
            }

            File file = new File(folder,"somefile.mp3");

            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);
                Log.w( "DOWNLOAD" , "progress " + downloadedSize + " / " + totalSize);

            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();

        //catch some possible errors...
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            Log.e( "DOWNLOAD" , "ERROR : " + e );
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e( "DOWNLOAD" , "ERROR : " + e );
        }
        return "done";
    }

    private void publishProgress( int i )
    {
        Log.v("DOWNLOAD", "PROGRESS ... " + i);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        if (result.equals("done")) 
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Thank you in advance, I hope someone will help me :)

DevJ

Comment: please write in comment reason for downvoting. it's unfair to downvote and hide,like a chicken.

Comment: I agree, I see nothing wrong with this question (It does seem that English is not the OPs original language, but we should ALWAYS make the effort to try understand, and ALWAYS leave a comment as to why)

Comment: Sorry for my poor english.. I do a lot of effort to speak well..

Comment: No apology necessary :) When you say it does not work (The android download), is there any error? Just it just lock up? A little more information on the nature of the failure may be helpfull.

Comment: No error returned, but always returns the progress like that : progress 33 / -1

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the initial URL contains a status 302 redirect to ANOTHER page that actually hosts or provides the mp3. There is a Java library called Jsoup that you can use to get to the actual mp3 file and download it. So let's say you have the initial URL of:
http://wscompany.name.com/downloadws/getDlFile/mdkHdKy97RppVWOsIOdDBuG/audio/1478

The first thing you should do is open up your browser, right click anywhere on the screen and choose "inspect element" or something similar so that you can monitor the network traffic. With the inspect element pane open, enter the above URL and you should see that it first goes to that URL (shows a status of 302 redirect), then goes to ANOTHER URL (possibly), before ending up at the destination (with a status 200). The status 200 page is the actual page you want. You can enter the above URL in Jsoup like this:

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://wscompany.name.com/downloadws/getDlFile/mdkHdKy97RppVWOsIOdDBuG/audio/1478").followredirect(true).header("","").header("",""). ...etc .post() or .get();

It returns a Document object (read the Jsoup documentation). This Document object can be parsed to get certain data...like OTHER URLs that you can also pass to the Jsoup.connect method, until you get to the actual mp3 you want to download with Android.

It will be important to look at the request headers listed in the "inspect element" pane and add those headers to the .connect() method by chaining them with multiple .header() methods.

I know this response is 2 years too late, but hopefully it will be helpful for anyone still needing to do what you were attempting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a network sniffer (like Wireshark) on desktop PC to see what exactly happens when requesting the MP3. My guess is that there is [a redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) to another URL.